# Load a log4j properties file and change programatically

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a scenario where I want to initialize multiple log4j loggers to write to their own files using a standard log4j.properties file as the basis for the properties. I then want to amend the properties within my code to setup the logger. In code i have been setting my Logger up like this:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jpropertiespath);
```

But then I need to be able to set the file appender and some properties like below. Specifically want to set Additivity to ensure logger instances keep their own log info, regardless of how many packages are created and loggers are initialized.

```
SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout();
FileAppender appender = new FileAppender(layout, logFileName, true);    
this.logger.setAdditivity(false);
this.logger.addAppender(appender);
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't think this is a great idea (to have an arbitrary number of log files, etcetera), but you could do this by wrapping the Logger.getLogger method, something like this

```
public static Logger getPackageLogger(String packageName) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(packageName);
    if (logger.getAppender("myPackageAppender") == null) {
        String logFileName = packageName + ".log"; // or something
        SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout();
        FileAppender appender = new FileAppender(
            layout, logFileName, true);    
        appender.setName("myPackageAppender");
        logger.setAdditivity(false);
        logger.addAppender(appender);
    }
    return logger;
}
```

This can be called multiple times, and should only configure each distinct (package) logger object once.

Comment: I ended up changing the implementation to use a more simple logging system. Thank you for the suggestion.